# ¿Por qué la suma de los montos solo considera la parte entera y omite los decimales?

Tags: javascript

Tengo algunos problemas con mi código javascript al momento de sumar valores de varios textbox. Sólo esta sumando valores enteros.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>DEMO</title>    
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Class="test" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Total<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="format(this)"></asp:TextBox>


    </form>
</body>

<script>
    function agregar_numero() {

        var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
        var TextBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
        var TextBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
        var result = TextBox1 + TextBox2 + TextBox3;
        result.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("txt4").value = result;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function format(input) {
        var num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '');
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
            num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
            input.value = num;
        }

        else {
            alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
            input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta usando la clase numberformat y/o intenta inicializar las variables como `var textbox = parseFloat(0);`

Comment: Cual es el objetivo de los regex?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz gracias por responder es para que separen el numero que estoy ingresando en el textbox ejemplo: 100000 = 100.000

Comment: Y es ahí donde te estás volando el punto decimal?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz si , solo suma los enteros no se porque, además me gustaría sumar millones tambien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que puede crear problemas con el JavaScript de la pregunta:

- Se hace `parseFloat` de los campos incluso cuando están vacíos, lo que resulta en un NaN y un total no esperado. Lo ideal sería que si el campo está vacío y el valor va a ser NaN se utilizase 0 en su lugar.

  Para lograr esto añade un `|| 0` en la asignación:

  ```
  var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value) || 0;
  var TextBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value) || 0;
  var TextBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value) || 0;
  ```
- Se hace `parseFloat` sin preprocesar el campo, lo cual puede dar problemas con el formato que usas. Por ejemplo: imagina que tienes el valor 1234, que formateado se ve 1.234; cuando haces parseFloat de 1.234, el navegador considera que 1 es la parte entera y 234 son decimales, cuando realmente lo que quieres es todo como parte entera.

  Para solucionar esto, utiliza `replace()`  de la misma manera que lo usas en la función de formato, de este modo se estará procesando correctamente como entero:

  ```
  var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value.replace(/\./g, ''));
  var TextBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value.replace(/\./g, ''));
  var TextBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value.replace(/\./g, ''));
  ```
- Cuando se cambia el valor del total, no se está  formateando como los otros campos. Simplemente añade una llamada a la función `format` pasándole como valor el elemento con el total:

  ```
  format(document.getElementById("txt4"));
  ```

Combinando todos estos cambios, el código se vería como en esta demo:

```js
function agregar_numero() {
  // quitas los puntos (para evitar problemas con los decimales) e inicializa a 0 si el campo esta vacio 
  var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value.replace(/\./g, '')) || 0;
  var TextBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value.replace(/\./g, '')) || 0;
  var TextBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value.replace(/\./g, '')) || 0;
  var result = TextBox1 + TextBox2 + TextBox3;
  result.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("txt4").value = result;
  
  // formatea el resultado para que aparezca igual que los otros numeros
  format(document.getElementById("txt4"));
}

function format(input) {
  var num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '');
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
    input.value = num;
  }
  else {
    alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txt1" class="test" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>
<input id="txt2" class="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>
<input id="txt3" class="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>
<br />
Total<br />
<input id="txt4" class="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="format(this)"/>
```

---

**Actualización:** Me preguntaron cómo se haría algo similar pero en lugar de utilizando puntos, usando comas para la separación de los miles y dejando el punto para los decimales. Por ejemplo, para admitir números como 123,123,123.12

Los cambios para lograr eso son sencillos:

- Actualizar todas las sustituciones y expresiones regulares de . a , (hay bastantes).
- En la función que formatea los números:

  - Separar la parte entera y los decimales
  - Hacer todas las operaciones de formateo con la parte entera
  - Volver a añadir la parte decimal después de formatear la entera

El resultado final quedaría así:

```js
function agregar_numero() {
  // quitas los puntos (para evitar problemas con los decimales) e inicializa a 0 si el campo esta vacio 
  var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value.replace(/,/g, '')) || 0;
  var TextBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value.replace(/,/g, '')) || 0;
  var TextBox3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt3").value.replace(/,/g, '')) || 0;
  var result = TextBox1 + TextBox2 + TextBox3;
  //console.log(TextBox1 + "__" + TextBox2 + "__" + TextBox3 + "__" + result);
  result.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("txt4").value = result;

  // formatea el resultado para que aparezca igual que los otros numeros
  format(document.getElementById("txt4"));
}

function format(input) {
  var num = input.value.replace(/\,/g, '');
  var decimales = "";
  if (num.indexOf(".") >= 0) { 
    decimales = "." + num.split(".")[1].substring(0,2); // sólo nos quedamos con los dos primeros decimales
    num = Math.floor(num); // redondeamos hacia abajo para quedarnos con la parte entera
  }
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\,?)(\d{3})/g, '$1,');
    // añadir los decimales al final!
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\,]/, '') + decimales;
    input.value = num;
  }
  else {
    alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\,\.]*/g, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txt1" class="test" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>
<input id="txt2" class="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>
<input id="txt3" class="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero();format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>
<br />
Total<br />
<input id="txt4" class="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="format(this)"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por darte la molestia de escribir comentarios me sirvio de mucho y nuevamente gracias por tu tiempo!